# Can someone explain how to solve/what is meant in the solution for these kinds of homogeneous differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a differential equation with solution $y(x)$ of the form:

$$y'=F\left(\frac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}\right) $$

The interesting case is the one where $a_1x+b_1y+c_1 \neq K(a_2x+b_2y+c_2)$; as this one can be easily solved by the change of variables $z=a_1x+b_2y$.

This case I've read in books and online that is to be solved by "moving the origin of coordinates the intersection point of the two lines". I understand that each algebraic expression in the quotient is a line. However, I don't understand how to carry out this process nor how it can arrive to a solution. My books don't offer examples for this case and I haven't found any online, so I'd like to get either an example or a more comprehensive explanation of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$y'=F\left(\frac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}\right) $$
Define variables $$X=x+p, Y=y+q$$ so that the constant term is eliminated, i.e.$$a_1p+b_1q+c_1 =0$$ and $$a_2p+b_2q+c_2=0 $$This gives you a system of equations in two variables which can be solved for p,q. Then
we get $\frac{dY}{dX}=F(\frac{a_1X+b_1Y}{a_2X+b_2Y})………………(1)$ 
because $dx=dX, dy=dY.$

Now put $Y=vX$ where $v$ is a function of X,
and write $$\frac{dY}{dX}=v+x\frac{dv}{dX}$$ Now substitute into (1) and the resulting equation can usually be solved using separation of variables or other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$y'=F\left(\frac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}\right) $$
Let $x=X+h, y=Y+k$ then $dx=dX, dy=dY$ and set $a_1h+b_1k+c_1=0$ and $a_2h+b_2k+c_2=0$. Find $h,k$. Then
we get

$\frac{dY}{dX}=F\left(\frac{a_1X+b_1 Y}{a_2X+b_2Y}\right)$

Next, used $Y=VX \implies \frac{dY}{dX}=X \frac{dV}{dX}+V$

$$X\frac{dV}{dX}=F\left(\frac{a_1+b_1 V}{a_2 +b_2 V}\right)-V$$
$$\implies \frac{dV}{F\left(\frac{a_1+b_1 V}{a_2 +b_2 V}\right)-V}=\frac{dX}{X}/$$
$$\implies \int\frac{dV}{F\left(\frac{a_1+b_1 V}{a_2 +b_2 V}\right)-V}=\int \frac{dX}{X}+C$$